# Docker gyp ERR! stack Error: not found: make

Tags: node.js, docker

I have a Docker image that I build from a file and on one system (Mac OS) it works and on another it doesnt.

Here is the Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

WORKDIR /

# Without interactive dialogue
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# Install required packages
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y wget gnupg2 software-properties-common git apt-utils vim dirmngr apt-transport-https ca-certificates zip

ENV NODE_VERSION=14

RUN wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.37.2/install.sh | bash
RUN . .$HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh \
    && nvm install $NODE_VERSION \
    && nvm alias default $NODE_VERSION \
    && nvm use default

# Install Wine from WineHQ Repository
RUN dpkg --add-architecture i386
RUN wget -qO- https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key | apt-key add -
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv F987672F
RUN apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main'
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y --install-recommends winehq-stable

# Installing mono
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
RUN sh -c 'echo "deb https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-bionic main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-stable.list'
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y mono-complete

RUN PROJECT_DIR=/root/project

WORKDIR /project
```

I call the Dockerfile and the build process which gets triggered in the Dockerfile with a Basfile looking like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# where $1 can be either development|test|production
# and $2 can be --sso if needed
docker build -t debian-wine-electron-builder:0.1 .
docker run --name electron-build -v ${PWD}:/project debian-wine-electron-builder:0.1 bash -i -c "cd project ;\
    npm install -g cordova ;\ 
    npm install -g gulp ;\
    npm i --no-progress ;\
    gulp copy-vendors ;\
    gulp build-electron --env $1 $2"
docker rm electron-build
```

This is the error getting produced on one system:

```sh
=> => transferring dockerfile: 1.31kB                                                                                                              0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => transferring context: 60B                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:latest                                                                                    2.5s
 => [ 1/17] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:latest@sha256:669e010b58baf5beb2836b253c1fd5768333f0d1dbcb834f7c07a4dc93f474be                            0.0s
 => CACHED [ 2/17] RUN apt-get update                                                                                                               0.0s
 => CACHED [ 3/17] RUN apt-get install -y wget gnupg2 software-properties-common git apt-utils vim dirmngr apt-transport-https ca-certificates zip  0.0s
 => CACHED [ 4/17] RUN wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.37.2/install.sh | bash     && . .$HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh     && nvm ins  0.0s
 => CACHED [ 5/17] RUN dpkg --add-architecture i386                                                                                                 0.0s
 => CACHED [ 6/17] RUN wget -qO- https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key | apt-key add -                                                      0.0s
 => CACHED [ 7/17] RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv F987672F                                                        0.0s
 => CACHED [ 8/17] RUN apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main'                                               0.0s
 => CACHED [ 9/17] RUN apt-get update                                                                                                               0.0s
 => CACHED [10/17] RUN apt-get install -y --install-recommends winehq-stable                                                                        0.0s
 => CACHED [11/17] RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF                   0.0s
 => CACHED [12/17] RUN sh -c 'echo "deb https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-bionic main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-  0.0s
 => CACHED [13/17] RUN apt-get update                                                                                                               0.0s
 => CACHED [14/17] RUN apt-get install -y mono-complete                                                                                             0.0s
 => CACHED [15/17] RUN PROJECT_DIR=/root/project                                                                                                    0.0s
 => CACHED [16/17] WORKDIR /project                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:876996f388b64ea28af2ae50968325be83bac1e2fd094afd5373c7e2c116a09d                                                        0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/debian-wine-electron-builder:0.1                                                                                 0.0s
 
Use 'docker scan' to run Snyk tests against images to find vulnerabilities and learn how to fix them
bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
npm WARN deprecated noty@3.2.0-beta-deprecated: no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated xmldom@0.1.31: Deprecated due to CVE-2021-21366 resolved in 0.5.0
+ project@1.4.0
added 126 packages from 148 contributors in 116.331s
bash:  : command not found
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
/root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.0/bin/gulp -> /root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.0/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules/gulp/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
 
+ gulp@4.0.2
added 324 packages from 220 contributors in 41.671s
npm WARN read-shrinkwrap This version of npm is compatible with lockfileVersion@1, but package-lock.json was generated for lockfileVersion@2. I'll try to do my best with it!
 
npm WARN rm not removing /project/project/node_modules/.bin/gulp as it wasn't installed by /project/project/node_modules/gulp-cli
 
> sqlite3@4.2.0 install /project/project/node_modules/sqlite3
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
 
node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download 
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(403): https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v4.2.0/node-v83-linux-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for sqlite3@4.2.0 and node@14.19.0 (node-v83 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: not found: make
gyp ERR! stack     at getNotFoundError (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at F (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at E (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
gyp ERR! stack     at /root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
gyp ERR! stack     at /root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
gyp ERR! stack     at /root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:191:21)
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.10.76-linuxkit
gyp ERR! command "/root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.0/bin/node" "/root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/project/project/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v83-linux-x64/node_sqlite3.node" "--module_name=node_sqlite3" "--module_path=/project/project/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v83-linux-x64" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v83"
gyp ERR! cwd /project/project/node_modules/sqlite3
gyp ERR! node -v v14.19.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.0/bin/node /root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/project/project/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v83-linux-x64/node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=/project/project/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v83-linux-x64 --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v83' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/project/project/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1058:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:293:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 5.10.76-linuxkit
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.0/bin/node" "/project/project/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /project/project/node_modules/sqlite3
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v14.19.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.11.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute '/root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.0/bin/node /root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/project/project/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v83-linux-x64/node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=/project/project/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v83-linux-x64 --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v83' (1)
npm WARN project@1.4.0 No repository field.
npm WARN project@1.4.0 No license field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: windows-build-tools@5.2.2 (node_modules/windows-build-tools):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for windows-build-tools@5.2.2: wanted {"os":"win32","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.12 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.12: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules/mocha/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
 
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sqlite3@4.2.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the sqlite3@4.2.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I'm really lost as I thought the whole idea of Docker would be that if you got a running and working image, this would then work everywhere where the docker engine could be installed so I though I'd ask here before I start trying to add/ alter my Dockerfile.

As far as I understand it has trouble finding the nvm/ node executable. When logging onto the docker container with an active bash shell and running `node --version` it runs fine and can find the node environment.

Comment: I think the main issue here is that NPM cannot download all needed packages, then tries to build it locally but also fails to download the sources to build it locally

Comment: Did you do something to resolve this issue?

Comment: As mentioned in my comment above. This had most likely something to do with the sys configuration and network settings.